# pcntl_sigwaitinfo and signal handlers

Tags: php, signals, posix, pcntl

I'm writing a daemon which periodcally does some work and sleeps some time before repeating it again. But it must still be responsive to outer impacts (i.e. termination request) while asleep.

I managed to implement sleep timeout with ALRM signal and termination with TERM signal (sample):

```php
// ...

declare(ticks = 1);

function do_work()
{
    echo "Doing some work.\n";
}

$term = FALSE;

$sighandler = function ($signal) use (&$term)
{
    if ($signal === SIGTERM)
    {
        pcntl_alarm(0);

        $term = TRUE;

        echo "TERM HANDLER\n";
    } else {
        echo "ALRM HANDLER\n";
    }
};

pcntl_signal(SIGALRM, $sighandler);
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, $sighandler);

while (!$term)
{
    do_work();

    // Kick myself after 2 seconds
    pcntl_alarm(2);

    // Wait for alarm or termination
    $signal = pcntl_sigwaitinfo(array(SIGTERM, SIGALRM), $info);

    pcntl_signal_dispatch();

    switch ($signal)
    {
        case SIGALRM: echo "ALRM SIGWI\n"; break;
        case SIGTERM: echo "TERM SIGWI\n"; $term = TRUE; break;
    }
}

// ...
```

But for Gods sake I can't figure out why the sighandler is never called. I get the following output:

```
$ php sigsample.php
Doing some work.
ALRM SIGWI
Doing some work.
ALRM SIGWI
Doing some work.
TERM SIGWI
```

And at the same time if I don't set this handler the script dies because of unhandler signal.

Am I missing somethind? Why is my signal handler function never called? Is it pcntl_sigwaitinfo() interferes?

And are there are any other means to implement timeout and signal handling at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not entirely unexpected.

You've asked for delivery to a signal handler (`pcntl_signal(...)`), but then also asked to accept the signal without invoking any handlers (`pcntl_sigwaitinfo(...)`).  Your OS gets to decide what happens in this case, and your OS (like mine) chooses to let `pcntl_sigwaitinfo()` win.

#### Background

A process can receive ("suffer?") a signal in two different ways:

1. **asynchronous *delivery***

   The signal induces some asynchronous action, typically killing the process or invoking a user-defined handler. [`pcntl_signal`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php) registers just such a handler.

   The underlying calls familiar to C programmers are [`signal`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/signal.html) and [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/sigaction.html).
2. **synchronous *acceptance***

   Special system functions note that a signal is pending, and remove it from the pending list, returning information about the signal to the process.  [`pcntl_sigwaitinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-sigwaitinfo.php) is such a function.

   The underlying calls are [`sigwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/sigwait.html), [`sigwaitinfo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/sigwaitinfo.html) and [`sigtimedwait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/sigtimedwait.html).

These two ways, *delivery* and *acceptance*, are [different](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_04.html) and **are not meant to be used together**.  AIX, for example, simply forbids ["[c]oncurrent use of **sigaction** and **sigwait**"](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.genprogc%2Fdoc%2Fgenprogc%2Fsignal_mgmt.htm).

(Related to the above is the concept of the signal mask, which can "block" signals, effectively forcing them to stay pending until accepted or until "unblocked" and delivered.)

Comment: Thanks. So is there another way to wait for signals without invoking `pcntl_sigwaitinfo`? I believe I tried everything and still could not achieve desired behavior.

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer was helpful, don't hesitate to upvote/accept it.  :)  Regarding another way to wait for signals, yes, there are a variety of techniques to handle them.  It's not clear to me what behavior you specifically want, however.  Perhaps a different question illustrating your desired behavior is in order?